# Find the area of a map (Xkm x Ykm) from the left & right longitude and latitude

Tags: openstreetmap, distance, area, latitude-longitude

How can the area of a map from OpenStreetMap be determined in the form of Xkm x Ykm, given the following information:

---

[image: Values of left & right longitude & latitude in OpenStreetMap]

---

- Left Longitude  = 103.554879
- Right Longitude = 103.740497
- Top Latitude    = 1.585770
- Bottom Latitude = 1.490873

Any ideas?

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/45861/find-the-area-of-a-map-xkm-x-ykm-from-the-left-right-longitude-and-latitude

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to calculate an area of a portion of the sphere.
In that case you can split a spherical quadrangle into two spherical triangles, calculate the area of each and sum them up.

Check out some basic [spherical trigonometry laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry).  That will tell you how calculate the diagonal of the quadrangle on a sphere.

Then, the area of each triangle can be found as:

```
area = (sum of angles) - Pi
```

Another approach would entail projecting the lat/lon coordinates into plane and calculate an area of the plane quadrangle. The projections usually cause area distortion unless you use equal-area projection.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess, you have to multiply `area` with R^2 to get something in m^2.